# Counting Colors in Conway's Game of Life

Tags: c++, c++11, console, game-of-life

I have a basic version of CGoL running with pdCurses. My goal was to have each newly spawned cell take on the dominant color of their neighbors (if a spawned cell is mostly surrounded by red, make it red). I managed to get a half-baked solution working, but it has a few problems, mainly:

- It requires another member vector to hold the frequency of colors
- It requires aforementioned vector to be marked as mutable so the constness of other functions isn't affected
- It required creating a struct to return duel results (the neighbor count, and the dominant color)
- The color frequency storage scheme is slightly confusing

If someone can think of a cleaner method of achieving this, I would appreciate it. I'll also take any other kind of critique you may have.

My main function to count the neighbors is:

```
NeighborData Population::getNeighborData(int x, int y, int depth) const {
    int count = 0;
    for (int cY = y - depth; cY <= y + depth; cY++) {
        if (cY < 0 || cY >= height) continue;
        for (int cX = x - depth; cX <= x + depth; cX++) {
            if (cX < 0 || cX >= width || (cX == x && cY == y)) continue;

            unsigned char color = getPointColor(cX, cY);

            if (color != '\0') {
                count += 1;
                colorFreqs[color] += 1;
            }

        }
    }
    unsigned char c = consumeColorFrequencies();
    return NeighborData(count,c);
}
```

- vector `colorFreqs` has a pre-allocated slot for each color (only 16 on my machine). Every time we check a color, we look up the color using the color as an index, and increment its count.
- `consumeColorFrequenices()` is the main function that I'm asking about. It "consumes" the frequency vector; returning the dominant color (or the first found color if more the one have an equal frequency)
- `NeighborData` is a small struct with 2 members: the count, and the dominant color. I needed a way to return both bits of data at once to my `decideLifeOf()` method.

`consumeColorFrequencies()`:

```
unsigned char Population::consumeColorFrequencies() const {
    int hIndex = 0, highest = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < colorFreqs.size(); i++) {
        unsigned char freq = colorFreqs[i];
        if (freq > highest) {
            hIndex = i, highest = freq;
        }
    }
    //Set all color frequencies to 0
    std::fill(colorFreqs.begin(), colorFreqs.end(), 0);
    return hIndex;
}
```

And, the target use:

```
void Population::decideLifeOf(int x, int y) {
    NeighborData nD = getNeighborData(x, y, 1);
    unsigned int ns = nD.count;
    unsigned char color = nD.color;

    if (ns < 2 || ns > 3) killPoint(x, y);
    else if (ns == 3) addPoint(x, y, color);
}
```

**Population.h:**

```
#ifndef POPULATION_H
#define POPULATION_H

#include <set>
#include <vector>

#include "curses.h"

struct NeighborData {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    unsigned char color = COLOR_WHITE;
    NeighborData(unsigned int ct, unsigned char cr);
};

class Population {
    //To hold the "finished" generation, and the generation
    // currently being constructed
    std::vector<unsigned char> cells;
    std::vector<unsigned char> newCells;
    //To temporarily hold frequencies of colors
    //Index is the color, value is the number of occurances
    mutable std::vector<unsigned int> colorFreqs;

    int width = 0, height = 0;

public:
    Population(int newWidth, int newHeight);

    bool pointIsOccupied(int x, int y) const;

    void addPoint(int x, int y, unsigned char color);
    void killPoint(int x, int y);

    unsigned char getPointColor(int x, int y) const;

    NeighborData getNeighborData(int x, int y, int depth = 1) const;

    void decideLifeOf(int, int);

    int getIndexOf(int, int) const;

    void replacePopulation();

    unsigned char consumeColorFrequencies() const;

};

unsigned char randomColor(unsigned char starting = 1);

#endif
```

**Population.cpp:**

```
#include "Population.h"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

#include "curses.h"

NeighborData::NeighborData(unsigned int ct, unsigned char cr) {
    count = ct, color = cr;
}

Population::Population(int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    width = newWidth;
    height = newHeight;

    cells.resize(width * height);
    newCells.resize(width * height);
    colorFreqs.resize(COLORS);
}

bool Population::pointIsOccupied(int x, int y) const {
    return cells[getIndexOf(x, y)] != '\0';
}

unsigned char Population::getPointColor(int x, int y) const {
    return cells[getIndexOf(x, y)];
}

void Population::addPoint(int x, int y, unsigned char color) {
    newCells[getIndexOf(x, y)] = color;
}

void Population::killPoint(int x, int y) {
    newCells[getIndexOf(x, y)] = '\0';
}

NeighborData Population::getNeighborData(int x, int y, int depth) const {
    int count = 0;
    for (int cY = y - depth; cY <= y + depth; cY++) {
        if (cY < 0 || cY >= height) continue;
        for (int cX = x - depth; cX <= x + depth; cX++) {
            if (cX < 0 || cX >= width || (cX == x && cY == y)) continue;
            unsigned char color = getPointColor(cX, cY);


            if (color != '\0') {
                count += 1;
                colorFreqs[color] += 1;
            }

        }
    }
    unsigned char c = consumeColorFrequencies();
    return NeighborData(count,c);
}

void Population::decideLifeOf(int x, int y) {
    NeighborData nD = getNeighborData(x, y, 1);
    unsigned int ns = nD.count;
    unsigned char color = nD.color;

    if (ns < 2 || ns > 3) killPoint(x, y);
    else if (ns == 3) addPoint(x, y, color);
}

int Population::getIndexOf(int x, int y) const {
    return y * width + x;
}

void Population::replacePopulation() {
    cells = newCells;
}

unsigned char randomColor(unsigned char starting) {
    return (rand() % (COLORS - starting)) + starting;
}

unsigned char Population::consumeColorFrequencies() const {
    int hIndex = 0, highest = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < colorFreqs.size(); i++) {
        unsigned char freq = colorFreqs[i];
        if (freq > highest) {
            hIndex = i, highest = freq;
        }
    }
    //Set all color frequencies to 0
    std::fill(colorFreqs.begin(), colorFreqs.end(), 0);
    return hIndex;
}
```

**World.h:**

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H

#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

#include "Population.h"

class World {

    Population pop;

    int worldWidth = 0, worldHeight = 0;

public:

    World(int, int);

    void compileOutput(std::string disp = "#") const;

    void simGeneration();

    void randomizeCells(double chanceOfLife = 0.3, int newSeed = -1);

};

#endif
```

**World.cpp:**

```
#include "World.h"

#include <iomanip>
#include <set>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

#include "curses.h"

World::World(int xMax, int yMax) :
    pop(xMax,yMax) {
    worldWidth = xMax;
    worldHeight = yMax;
}

void World::compileOutput(std::string disp) const {
    for (int cY = 0; cY < worldHeight; cY++) {
        for (int cX = 0; cX < worldWidth; cX++) {
            char c = pop.getPointColor(cX, cY);
            init_pair(c, c, COLOR_BLACK);   //(Pair number, fore color, back color)
            attron(COLOR_PAIR(c));
            mvprintw( cY, cX, (pop.pointIsOccupied(cX, cY) ? disp.c_str() : " ") );
            attroff(COLOR_PAIR(c));
        }
    }
}


void World::simGeneration() {
    for (int y = 0; y < worldHeight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++) {
            pop.decideLifeOf(x,y);
        }
    }
    pop.replacePopulation();
}

void World::randomizeCells(double chanceOfLife, int newSeed) {
    if (newSeed > 0) srand(newSeed);
    for (int y = 0; y < worldHeight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++) {
            if ((rand() % int(1.0 / chanceOfLife)) == 0) {
                unsigned char color = randomColor();
                pop.addPoint(x, y, color);
            }
        }
    }
    pop.replacePopulation();
}
```

**Timer.h:**

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include <chrono>

class Timer {

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start;

public:
    Timer();

    void restart();

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now();

    double getMS();
    double getSecs();
};

#endif
```

**Timer.cpp:**

```
#include "Timer.h"

#include <ctime>


Timer::Timer() {
    start = now();
}

void Timer::restart() {
    start = now();
}

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point Timer::now() {
    return std::chrono::system_clock::now();
}

double Timer::getMS() {
    return (now() - start).count() / 10000.0;
}

double Timer::getSecs() {
    return getMS() / 1000.0;
}
```

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include "World.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include "curses.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;

    initscr();                    /* Start curses mode */
    start_color();

    noecho();                   // Don't echo any keypresses
    curs_set(FALSE);            // Don't display a cursor

    const long maxX = 60, maxY = 40;

    World w(maxX, maxY);

    w.randomizeCells(0.4, 10);

    double lastDur = 1;
    Timer t;
    for (int rounds = 0; rounds < 5000; rounds++) {
        clear();

        w.compileOutput("#");
        mvprintw(maxY + 1, 0, "%d", rounds);

        w.simGeneration();

        lastDur = t.getMS(); t.restart();
        mvprintw(maxY + 2, 0, "%0.1f fps", 1000.0 / lastDur);

        refresh();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds( 50 ) );
    }


    endwin();
}
```

Comment: If `colorFreqs` is a temporary, then why don't you convert it into a local variable in `getNeighborData` and pass it as a parameter to `consumeColorFrequencies`?

Comment: @MikeMB I made it a member instead of a local so it wouldn't need to be constantly created/destroyed on every "scan".

Comment: If the number of colors is fixed, just use a local `std::array`. The overhead for construction and destruction is zero.

Comment: @MikeMB What does that give me? Fixing the `mutable` problem? Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: And it would allow you to parallelize your `simGeneration` method and possibly even increase your single threaded performance

Comment: @MikeMB My first test will be comparing the performance of the member vector vs a local array. I have yet to do any multithreading in c++, so before I try that here, I'll probably want to mess around on a smaller project first. I'll give it a try though. Thanks for the idea. Out of curiosity, what did you have in mind for `simGeneration`? Generate generation "frames" on one thread, and display them with another?

Comment: I'd be very interested in the outcome of your performance measurements.

Comment: @mikeMB I ran into a minor snag. I thought the curses-supplied value of my machine's capacity for colors (`COLORS`) was a compile-time constant; turns out it's not. Now I'm thinking I'll need to make the amount of colors some arbitrary number, but I don't know what the behavior will be if it's run on a system with a lower capacity than the number I chose.

Comment: @mikeMB VERY interesting results. I ran 1000 rounds on a 90x45 grid, with a seed of 2, and a spawn chance of 0.4. The member vector averaged 34.982 seconds; with a range of 34.797 to 35.122. The local array averaged 29.748; but its range was a lot bigger. Its shortest time was 19.585 seconds, all the way to 38.607 seconds. Why did the array perform more inconsistently?

Comment: @MikeMB Because I didn't need any of the extras of `std::array`, I changed it to a `const unsigned char*`, and it's down to ~14 seconds; and as a bonus, it's far more consistent. Idk what `std::array` was doing, but I was getting times from 13 seconds to almost 40. It was "consistently inconsistent", while `vector` and normal arrays had fairly steady times. I'm very glad I posted this.

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't know where the big variations come from but I'm a little supprised about the difference between `std::array` and c-style array (You passed the std::array by reference right?) because it should be translated into the same code. What compiler and optimization level have you used?

Comment: Yes, the `std::array` was passed by reference. And it's on Visual Studio, so whatever the default arguments are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22736/discussion-between-mikemb-and-carcigenicate).

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/88232/9357)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your general approach (or at least I don't have a better suggestion).
On an implementation level I've a few suggestions

1. As mentioned before, I'd replace the class member `mutable std::vector<unsigned int> colorFreqs;` with a local `std::array<size_t, COLORS> colorFreqs{};`  in `getNeighborData` and pass the array as a const ref parameter to `consumeColorFrequencies`. This gets rid of the mutable problem and might even increase performance.
2. I'd write the `getNeighborData` function a little different:

   ```
   NeighborData Population::getNeighborData(int x, int y, int depth) const {
       std::array<unsigned char, COLORS> colorFreqs{};
       int count = 0;
       for (int cY = std::max(0, y - depth); cY <= std::min(height-1, y + depth); cY++) {      
           for (int cX = std::max(0, x - depth); cX <= std::min(width-1, x + depth); cX++) {
               if (cX == x && cY == y) continue;
               unsigned char color = getPointColor(cX, cY);
               if (color != '\0') {
                   count++;
                   colorFreqs[color]++;
               }
           }
       }
       unsigned char c = consumeColorFrequencies(colorFreqs);
       return NeighborData(count, c);
   }
   ```

   Whether that is easier to understand than your version is up for discussion, but it should be a little more efficient.
3. `consumeColorFrequencies`can be simplified by using an STL algorithm:

   ```
   unsigned char Population::consumeColorFrequencies(const std::array<unsigned char, COLORS>& colorFreqs) const {
       auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(colorFreqs), std::end(colorFreqs));
       return std::distance(std::begin(colorFreqs),it);
   }
   ```
4. In response to the comment about multithreading: You can (more or less) trivially parallelize `compileOutput` by letting each thread generate the new cells for a slice of the world (e.g. a quarter of the rows on a 4-Core machine). There are many parallel loop implementations out there that can make that Task even easier. Obviously this is only sensible for very large grids.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. It should be noted though, as I said in the comments that `COLORS` isn't actually a compile-time constant, so I ended up using a macro that defined `NCOLORS` as 16. I don't know what this will do on a machine with less than that many colors though. That'll probably be my next test.

Comment: And is there a reason you use `std::begin(colorFreqs)` instead of `colorFreqs.begin()`? And I'm guessing the call to `std::distance` gives you the index number of the iterator?

Comment: Amazingly, my version of `consumeColorFrequencies` is faster (29.748 vs 38.739 seconds).

Comment: @Carcigenicate: You mean the version without STL-algorithm? If it has such a strong impact, then use your own version. About `std::begin` and `end`: No special reason just my personal preference.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I just realized I made a mistake: I wrote `std::array<size_t, COLORS>` when it should have been `std::array<unsigned char, COLORS>`.

Comment: I didn't notice that. I used `unsigned char` in my test.

Answer (score 4):

@MikeMB answer already covers some interesting points, but there are still some more things that you could improve in your code:

- In your class `Timer`, you should `const`-qualify the methods `now`, `getMS` and `getSecs` since they don't modify the `Timer` instance when called. Whether you want `now` to be `static` or not is up to you.
- Also, it is useless to specify by yourself the seconds/milliseconds conversions, the standard library already does that for you:

  ```
  double Timer::getMS() const {
      std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now() - start).count();
  }

  double Timer::getSecs() const {
      std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now() - start).count();
  }
  ```

  Actually, you could have only one function template that takes a type parameter for the seconds/milliseconds/etc... That would make a more flexible interface, while still abstracting away the `std::chrono::duration_cast` and the subtraction:

  ```
  template<typename Duration>
  double Timer::getElapsedTime() const {
      std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(now() - start).count();
  }
  ```
- At some point, you use the following piece of code:

  ```
  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds( 50 ) );
  ```

  It is fine, no problem. However, if you have access to a C++14 compiler, you might want to use the standard library user-defined literals to make it simpler:

  ```
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);
  ```
- You could initialize every member of `World` in its constructor initialization list instead of initializing one member in the constructor initialization list and two members in the constructor body:

  ```
  World::World(int xMax, int yMax) :
      pop(xMax, yMax),
      worldWidth(xMax),
      worldHeight(yMax)
  {}
  ```
- The function `consumeColorFrequencies` can probably be written in terms of [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

  ```
  unsigned char Population::consumeColorFrequencies() const {
      // Find the index of the highest frequency
      auto it = std::max_element(colorFreqs.begin(), colorFreqs.end());
      auto hIndex = std::distance(colorFreqs.begin(), it);

      //Set all color frequencies to 0
      std::fill(colorFreqs.begin(), colorFreqs.end(), 0);
      return hIndex;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if VS 2013 supports c++14; I haven't even looked into what goodies 14 brings. I'm glad they made times easier to enter though; the chrono class leads to some ugly code. And I don't know why I go back and forth between initialization lists and using the constructor body; i haven't found my preference yet. Your example is neater though. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: @Carcigenicate When possible, always use constructor initialization list: it ensures that the object is *constructed* with the values you feed it. If you initialize in the constructor body, then the object will be constructed, then its fields will be modified.

Comment: @Carcigenicate VS 2013 doesn't support user-defined literals, so the C++14 standard library one can't have been added. I guess that they will be present in VS 2015.

Comment: Good point, thank you. And oh well. I survived this long writing long `chrono` namespace chains. That will be  cool feature. They should just include implicits like Scala, then the user can just define such things with an implicit class.